# assign string.empty when SelectSingleNode.value not found

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am passing a few parameters to a webservice and parse it out of the XML doc by using`XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter/LastName").Value`etc. The problem is if the node does not have a value I get an object reference exception.  I still need to pass this as a string.empty param to my web service.  I understand i need to handle this exception but is there a way I could do it in one line. for example

```
string/variable lname = payloadXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter/LastName").Value ?? "";
```

**xslt template**

```
    <xsl:element name="ssn">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="count(//Transaction/Parameter[@Name='LastName'])>0">
                     <xsl:value-of select="//Transaction/Parameter[@Name='LastName']/@Value"/>
                   </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                 </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
```

**Web Service Call:**

```
response = client.ExecLocalSearch(XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter/LastName").Value, "//Parameter/info").Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close!  The `SelectSingleNode()` call will return `null` if the node is not found, so calling `.Value` on that will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  However, you could use the ["safe navigation operator"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) (`?.`) to forward the `null` along so that your null coalescing operator (`??`) will see the `null` and return an empty string instead.  So your first line would look like this:

```
payloadXmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Parameter/LastName")?.Value ?? "";
```

So if the node isn't found, instead of calling `.Value`, the `null` is used instead, thus the `??` will see the `null` and return an empty string.

Comment: awesome :-).  thanks. im a fan of the safe navigation operator now.